# How to convert factor levels to list, in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, r-factor

Imagine a data frame such as df1 below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = as.factor(c("m0p1", "m5p30", "m11p20", "m59p60", "m59p60")))
```

How do I create a list of all the levels of a variable? Thank you.

Comment: `levels(df1$v1)` will give you a character vector of levels.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869539/confusion-between-factor-levels-and-factor-labels

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To print the levels in the variable, use `levels()` as @scoa says:

```
levels(df1$v1)
```

To make it an explicit list use `as.list()` as well:

```
l <- as.list(levels(df1$v1))
l
```

Answer (score 4):

This converts the factor to something manageable:

```
df1$v1 <- vapply(df1$v1, paste, collapse = ", ", character(1L))
```

Comment: you can do the same more simply with `as.caracter(df1$v1)'