# Converting a vector to factor in R and keeping undeclared levels

Tags: r

I want to convert a character vector in R to a factor (let's take the example from the DataCamp Introduction to R course) and would like to label a few of the factor levels. How do I avoid, that any unmentioned/undeclared levels are automatically put to NA?

```
speed_vector <- c("fast", "slow", "slow", "fast", "insane")

factor_speed_vector <- factor(speed_vector, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("slow", "insane"), labels = c("Speed < 30 mph", "Speed > 100 mph"))
```

results in

```
> summary(factor_speed_vector)
 Speed < 30 mph Speed > 100 mph            NA's 
              2               1               2 
> factor_speed_vector
[1] <NA>            Speed < 30 mph  Speed < 30 mph  <NA>            Speed > 100 mph
Levels: Speed < 30 mph < Speed > 100 mph
```

How can I make sure that any undefined factor level (like "fast" in this example) gets carried over with the original value instead of being set to NA?

**Edit:**
My previous comment here, was due to a confusion of the level and labels option in the factor function. Anybody, also not knowing the difference can read up here: [Confusion between factor levels and factor labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869539/confusion-between-factor-levels-and-factor-labels)

Comment: what do you want to do with a value that is not a level of your factor though? Add it as a new factor?

Comment: @useR I just want to make sure that when converting vectors to factors in a larger dataset with a larger number of factor levels that data is not automatically set to NA, just because I missed to declare a level. So mt1022, it is actually irrelevant what the labels are, I just added them, so the first comment would not be why I don't use `factor()` without defining levels at all. The reason to define levels is that I want to give labels to them.

Comment: Maybe you want to start with `factor_speed_vector <- factor(c("fast", "slow", "slow", "fast", "insane"), ordered = TRUE)` to better replicate your situation?

Comment: So are you asking for a way to convert a vector to a factor with levels automatically set to all unique values in the vector? Just use `as.factor()`

Comment: @useR; that doesn't work because, you can't order and label the levels in as.factor

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869539/confusion-between-factor-levels-and-factor-labels

Comment: @useR: No, I am asking to convert some of the unique values as declared in the `levels` option and not to omit the remaining unique values, but treat them instead as `as.factor()` would do.

Comment: Do you necessarily want your resulting factor to be ordered? If yes, what should be the relative order of known (here `"slow"` and `"insane"`) and "unknown" factors (here `"fast"`)? If no, consider `forcats::fct_recode(
  as.factor(speed_vector),
  "Speed < 30 mph" = "slow",
  "Speed > 100 mph" = "insane"
)` (not better than already posted answers, but more readable, at least to me)

Comment: @Aurèle: Thanks for the Link, I think part of my confusion originates from not fully understanding factor levels and labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `levels` and `match`, you can do the following.

Start with a factor variable:

```
factor_speed_vector <- factor(c("fast", "slow", "slow", "fast", "insane"), ordered = TRUE)
```

Then, change the levels of the variable pulling the proper indices with `match`

```
levels(factor_speed_vector)[match(c("slow", "insane"), levels(factor_speed_vector))] <-
c("Speed < 30 mph", "Speed > 100 mph")
```

Here, `match(c("slow", "insane"), levels(factor_speed_vector))` finds the indices for the factor levels matching "slow" and "insane". These indices are used to subset the levels and then the new labels are fed in.

Answer (score 2):

The `forcats` package has some nice helper functions to deal with factors. The `fct_recode()` function lets you change factor levels by hand. You can specify a sequence of named character vectors where the name gives the new level, and the value gives the old level. *Levels not otherwise mentioned will be left as is.*  (from `?fct_recode`, emphasis mine).

```
speed_vector <- c("fast", "slow", "slow", "fast", "insane")
speed_vector
```

> ```
> [1] "fast"   "slow"   "slow"   "fast"   "insane"
> ```

```
forcats::fct_recode(speed_vector, "Speed < 30 mph" = "slow", "Speed > 100 mph" = "insane")
```

> ```
> [1] fast            Speed < 30 mph  Speed < 30 mph  fast            Speed > 100 mph
> Levels: fast Speed > 100 mph Speed < 30 mph
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This function seems really convenient and solves the problem just as fine. I accepted another answer, because it only uses base R.

Answer (score 1):

Would this suit you ?

```
speed_vector <- c("fast", "slow", "slow", "fast", "insane")
factor_speed_vector <- factor(speed_vector)
levels(factor_speed_vector)[factor_speed_vector == "slow"]   <- "Speed < 30 mph"
levels(factor_speed_vector)[factor_speed_vector == "insane"] <-  "Speed > 100 mph"
factor_speed_vector
# [1] fast            Speed < 30 mph  Speed < 30 mph  fast            Speed > 100 mph
# Levels: fast Speed > 100 mph Speed < 30 mph
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I like the readability of the code. I accepted another answer, because it would require less code typing in case of use with more factor levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
factor_speed_vector = as.factor(speed_vector)

# > levels(factor_speed_vector)
# [1] "fast"   "insane" "slow"

levels(factor_speed_vector)[3:2] = c("Speed < 30 mph", "Speed > 100 mph")

# > factor_speed_vector
# [1] fast            Speed < 30 mph  Speed < 30 mph  fast            Speed > 100 mph
# Levels: fast Speed > 100 mph Speed < 30 mph
```

Comment: Thanks @useR. I think compared to the other solutions, this one is not so flexible, since it needs explicit addressing of the position in the label vector.

Comment: @m.a.m I agree, but this is more convenient if your factor levels don't change. Feel free to accept the other answers.