# Factor coercion produces a numeric label for *each* row in data frame, not the labels specified

Tags: r, r-factor

I am trying to coerce numeric columns in a data frame to factors. The coercion works OK except that instead of the labels I specify I get a numeric label for each row of the data frame. There are no error messages.

I've tried tidyverse and base approaches; coerced the target vector to character (and even to integer) before coercing to factor; run the same code over a tibble rather than a data frame just in case it was to do with the row names. And I have searched here and other R-related parts of the internet.

I feel sure I am missing something obvious here, but as happens when one looks at a problem for too long, I just can't see it.

```
df <- data.frame("a" = c(1, 2, 2), "b" = c(2, 1, 1), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$a <- factor(df$a, levels = c("1", "2"), labels = c("yes", "no"))

# coercion to factor worked:
class(df$a)
#> [1] "factor"
typeof(df$a)
#> [1] "integer"

levels(df$a)
#> [1] "yes" "no"
labels(df$a)  # same as no. rows in df. Add rows and more labels appear.
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"
df$a
#> [1] yes no  no 
#> Levels: yes no
```

*Created on 2020-09-24 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)*

Comment: Levels and labels in r can cause confusion as they are different to some other systems. This might help clear it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869539/confusion-between-factor-levels-and-factor-labels

Comment: Thanks NColl. I did read that one before I posted; Joris Meys' answer was very clear, but it doesn't address the problem I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can look at the structure of `df$a` using `dput`:

```r
dput(df$a)
#> structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("yes", "no"), class = "factor")
```

You can see that it is indeed a factor with the appropriate labels. The function `labels` that you are using does not return the `.Label` element of a factor. It is completely unrelated to factors, and I think you are just confused by the name. The `labels` function simply gives a character vector of numbers the same length as the input vector, whatever the class is. For example:

```r
labels(5:10)
#> [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"
```

So there is nothing wrong with your newly created factor. The `levels` function rather confusingly returns the `.Label` component of the factor.

Factors do not actually have a named component called "levels". The `levels` parameter in the function `factor` is only used sometimes when creating a factor from a character or numeric vector so that we specify which elements of our vector we are interested in. In your case, the `levels` argument of the `factor` call is completely redundant:

```
df <- data.frame("a" = c(1, 2, 2), "b" = c(2, 1, 1), row.names = NULL)
factor(df$a, labels = c("yes", "no"))
#> [1] yes no  no 
#> Levels: yes no
```

We would only use it if we wanted to drop some levels:

```
factor(df$a, levels = "2", labels = "no")
#> [1] <NA> no   no  
#> Levels: no
```

I think you may have been looking for:

```r
as.numeric(df$a)
#> [1] 1 2 2
```

to get the original numbers back.

However, there is no error. Your coercion is correct and works exactly as intended. It is only your understanding of what the `labels` function is supposed to do that is causing a problem.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you Allan. That makes a confusing situation much clearer. There's probably a moral there about computer science and naming things, I suppose. I have added `dput()` to my toolbox, so thank you for that too.